# How to has_one/belongs_to association only return the objects unassociated in combobox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models (Car and Driver) and a combobox to select which driver belongs to which car.
I want the combobox just show the objects that have not yet been associated.

```
# vehicle 
belongs_to: driver 

# driver 
has_one: vehicle 

# simple_form 
# vehicle/_form.html.haml 
= f.association: driver, label_method: :name, value_method: :id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own collection to the association input, like:

```
= f.association :driver, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, collection: Driver.not_assigned_to_a_vehicle
```

If you don't already have a scope on `Driver` that would return all drivers without a `Vehicle`, you need to add one:

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...

    scope :not_assigned_to_a_vehicle, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.driver_id = drivers.id").where(vehicles: { id: nil }) }

    ...

end
```

Comment: I got the same result using: `scope :not_assigned_to_a_vehicle, -> {Driver.includes(:vehicle).where(vehicles: {id: nil})}`. Thanks